# evidence siloka that four YOGAs for self realization

Tags: scripture, vedas, yoga

Namaste (^o^),I need an evidence siloka that four YOGAs such as Bhakti,Karma,Gyana and Astanga are 4 principle margas for self realization.Thank you.

Comment: I think it is mentioned in the Gita.

Comment: you are asking the  whole of Gita as answer for this question.. its not one sloka answer are few. but very good question..